# Взаимодействие объектов

Tags: swift, spritekit

При соприкосновении объектов у меня появляется текст, можно ли сделать, чтобы он появлялся именно в том месте, где объекты соприкоснулись? https://yadi.sk/d/Inp2b0wptcKEv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в `didBeginContact` передается объект contact, у которого есть свойство contactPoint. Это точка, где произошло столкновение, туда вам и надо поставить свой UILabel.

Один нюанс, который надо учесть: точка 0-0 физического мира приходится на левый нижний угол, а UILabel считает координаты из левого верхнего, чтобы получить координату вертикальнго положения лэйбла, вам надо будет отнять физическую координату от размера сцены.

UPDATE:
оказывается у вас сцена не совпадает по размерам с экраном - экран в поинтах 320х568, а сцена 640х1136

Несколько уточнений:

вот так я посчитал куда ставить label

```
if ((contactBody1.categoryBitMask == 2) && (contactBody2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Ball)) {
    var reverse = CGPointMake(contact.contactPoint.x/2, contact.contactPoint.y/2)
    reverse.y = self.view!.bounds.size.height - reverse.y
    PX.center = reverse
    self.view?.addSubview(PX)
}
```

не забыть поставить текст label по центру

```
PX.textAlignment = .Center
```

и если вы хотите чтобы сцена нормально выглядела на любом устройстве

```
self.scene?.size = CGSize(width: self.view!.frame.size.width*2, height: self.view!.frame.size.height*2)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за развернутый ответ)

Answer (score 1):

Точку соприкосновения можете прочитать из `contact.contactPoint` и использовать эти данные для указания координат Вашей `UILabel`